# How do I tell puppeteer when the page is fully loaded?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, async-await, puppeteer

I have some things which load asyncronously, so I need puppeteer to wait until they are finished loading.

I've tried waiting for a variable to be set

```
await page.waitForFunction('window.exampleLoaded === true');
```

I've tried waiting for an element to appear

```
await page.waitForSelector('#complete');
```

And I put this code directly in the javascript for the page:

```
window.exampleLoaded = true;
document.body.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend','<div id="complete"></div>');
```

But puppeteer just times out, those waitFor's never resolve.

If i just open the page in the browser, both `window.exampleLoaded === true` and `document.querySelector('#complete')!=null` are true.

EDIT: If I put them at the very top of the code, then the awaits resolve. But not if they're triggered later.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It's hard to say without a [mcve] and the URL or a relevant snippet/mock of the page you're working with. Every page has unique behavior so there is no one-size-fits-all page loaded logic.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was something else on the page, but this code was very helpful in figuring out the problem:

```
page
.on('console', message =>
  console.log(`${message.type().substr(0, 3).toUpperCase()} ${message.text()}`))
.on('pageerror', ({ message }) => console.log(message))
.on('response', response =>
  console.log(`${response.status()} ${response.url()}`))
.on('requestfailed', request =>
  console.log(`${request.failure().errorText} ${request.url()}`))
```